# How to import CSV and Then Select Column in Python Script (Orange)

Tags: python, orange

In Orange, there is Data widget for import `CSV` file, and Select Column widget to choose feature, target, and meta.

How to do that with Python `Script` widget?

For example:

```
CSV file = D:\passenger\data.csv
feature = age | gender | job
meta  = name
target = seat_class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python Script widget, the following should work:

```
from Orange import Table
# load your path
data = Table('D:\passenger\data.csv')
```

Comment: it works but only for import csv , but how choose feature, meta, target ?

Comment: One way is to construct an appropriate header. See: https://orange-visual-programming.readthedocs.io/loading-your-data/index.html#three-row-header-format

Answer (score 0):

If CSV file is in the same folder as your python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list

with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)   # skip header in 1st row
    for row in reader:
        for (i,v) in enumerate(row):
            columns[i].append(v)

print('Column 1 Values: ', columns[0])
print('Column 2 Values: ', columns[1]) 
print('Column 3 Values: ', columns[2])
```

Contents of data.csv:

```
age,gender,job
25,M,IT
35,F,Operations
```

Output:

```
Column 1 Values:  ['25', '35']
Column 2 Values:  ['M', 'F']
Column 3 Values:  ['IT', 'Operations']
```